# Compare two source and update sql server table in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have excel source and sql server table .

Excel Source column is

```
 Mno    Price1  Price2
 111     10      20
 222     30      25
 333     40      30
 444      34      09
 555      23      abc
```

Sql server Table

Product table name

```
  PId    Mno    Sprice   BPrice
    1      111    3        50
    2      222    14        23
    3      444    32       34
    4      555    43       45  
    5      666    21       67
```

I want to compare excel source Mno(Model number) with sql server Product table Mno (Model number), and if it is same i want to update Sql server Product table SPrice and Bprice.

Please tell me what are the steps i want to do?

I want to validate that excel sheet also, because in excel Price2 column have string values

if it's string value i want to send mail which row data are wrong.

I am new for SSIS so please give me details.

Answer (score 1):

Read your new data in a source, use a lookup component for existing data. Direct row matches to a oledb command for update, and a destination for your non-matches for inserts (if you want to enter new products).

Comment: This is commonly referred to as an "upsert"

Comment: Indeed it is. It's basically the simplest way to do it in SSIS, without caring if the data matched is different or not, which you could work with by having a conditional split on the price column (or other columns you want to update) to avoid having a sql command for every row, but as long as the source data is small, the time it takes is probably negligable.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the simplest way to do this is to use a dataflow to bring the excel file into a staging table and do any clean up if need be. Then as the next step inmteh control flow have an Execute SQl task that does the update. Or if you need either an update or an insert if the record is new, use a Merge statement in the Execute SQl task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Merge Join Transformation with a full outer join (remember to sort your datasets before they input to the Merge Join Transformation), then have the output go to a Conditional Split Transformation. The Conditional Split Transformation can determine whether or not a row needs to be updated, inserted, or deleted and direct the flow to the appropriate transform to do that.

This was off the top of my head, and there may be a simpler transform for this. I haven't had the opportunity to work with SSIS in almost a year, so I might be getting a bit rusty.